# Epson L3150 printer driver

Tags: epson

How can I install Epson L3150 ink tank printer in Ubuntu? I failed to install using the deb file given in the site

Comment: How did you "fail to install"?

Comment: while installation failed to find out driver when searching for drivers. In 18.04 only generic printer added, and printer working without printing

Comment: Download a driver from Epson site and install it. And what "installation" was searching for drivers?

Comment: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult

Comment: If installation fails, run `sudo apt install -f` to install dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

1. Follow [this link](https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult?productName=L3150&osCode=LX), in the search box type "L3150" and in the dropdown menu choose "Linux".
2. Press "Download" next to "ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver)".
3. Press "Accept" and then download the driver file named
   `epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_XXXX-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`
   (even if your processor is not AMD) where instead of XXXX will be the current version number.
4. Install using GDebi:
   First just try to open the file, which will open GDebi's gui, and click install. If that doesn't work, open a terminal, browse to appropriate folder, and run
   `sudo gdebi epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_XXXX-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb` (don't forget to replace XXXX with version number).
   Or using APT: `sudo apt install ./epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_XXXX-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`
5. Go to Printers, press `Add`, let it find your printer (note whether it is connected directly via USB or via the network) and proceed in the obvious way to set the printer.

Comment: Fantastic, just followed those steps and printed successfully first time, thank you. @Santhosh-v you should mark this as accepted, it's tested and working.

Comment: And will that work in both scanning and printing ? I will install for Epson EcoTank M3170 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: @Nukool I haven't tried scanning, please share your experience if you try

Comment: It works perfectly!

Comment: this link doesn't work anymore(

Comment: @porfirion I just tried it and it worked

Comment: works, thanks a lot !

Comment: @UrYa'ar seems it is blocked for some locations( I've managed to download using anonymizer