# Epson M3170 printer one driver for scanning and printing

Tags: epson

I used to install all-in-one driver for Brother MFC-J430W, that was easy in selecting and installing driver.
Now I just bought Epson Ecotank M3170, it is not easy to install.
Is [this answer to the question on model L3150](https://askubuntu.com/a/1306864) can be applied with model M3170 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ?
And will that work in both scanning and printing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download Epson Linux drivers here

https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

You will need the `ESC/P-R Driver 2 (generic driver)` and the `Scanner Driver`.

You don't really need `gdebi`. The printer deb package can be installed by

```
sudo apt install ./<file_name>
```

The package should be in your Home directory. Otherwise you will have to provide path to it.

The scanner driver is usually installed by the `install.sh` script.